# How to calculate number of working days between two months like from Jan to May in excel?

Tags: excel

Suppose a user selects a `From` month from a dropdown (e.g. January) and a `To month` from a second dropdown (e.g. May). I have to show number of working days from jan to may in a third column..how can we calculate it?

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want someone to supply code or a formula?  You can work it out by using `DATEVALUE` and `NETWORKDAYS`.  Also, you may need to take into account a situation where you pick, for example, Sep as the **From** month, and Feb as the **To** month.  Edit your question to show your attermpts, and the problems that you have run into.

Comment: Start Month End Month Total proeesional days
Jul                   Mar          After selecting values for start and end month from dropdown,Automatically proffessional days should be calculated in professional days cell

Comment: What have you done to try to solve your problem?  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And what happened when you tried to apply the information provided here by others?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the name of the function is `NETWORKDAYS`

Comment: NETWORKDAYS accept only numeric character as i have to select days between two months its giving wrong data type error when select from an to months from dropdown...NETWORKDAYS not workinh

Comment: @mays This may work, `=NETWORKDAYS(DATEVALUE("1 " & "Jan" & " 2016"),DATEVALUE ("31" & "May" & " 2016")) ` . I am on my phone and away from anything to test. But it should give some guidance.

Comment: Hey scott its working..but its for only specific months though we have to set datvalue here each and everytime....i have to select from month form dropdown and end month too from dropdown..and after that Number of working days should be auto calculated in third cell.,.,.is it possible?

Comment: @mays sorry change the months part to there respective cells. So `"Jan"` would be `A1` or what ever cell it it is.  And the same for May.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way I have done this work in the past. Start with a table that lists for every day whether or not it's a work day during the timeframe you are interested int.

```
date    workday?
1/1/15  1
1/2/15  1
1/3/15  0
1/4/15  0
1/5/15  1
1/6/15  1
1/7/15  1
1/8/15  1
1/9/15  1
1/10/15 0
1/11/15 0
1/12/15 1
1/13/15 1
1/14/15 1
1/15/15 1
1/16/15 1
1/17/15 0
1/18/15 0
1/19/15 1
...
```

in a second sheet, use a function like this:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(A2<=MONTH('workdays 2015'!A$2:A$366)),--(B2>=MONTH('workdays 2015'!A$2:A$366)),('workdays 2015'!B$2:B$366))
```

where A2 is the beginning month as an integer (jan = 1 feb = 2 etc) and b2 is the end month. the array A2:A366 is where you put the dates and the array b2:B366 is where you put ones for workdays and 0 for weekends/holidays.

Comment: This seems cumbersome compared with the  `NETWORKDAYS` function